# Toggle text when link is clicked

Tags: jquery, onclick, toggle, slidetoggle

I have the below code that toggles a div (called `#extra`) into view:

```
$('#more').click(function() {
    $('#extra').slideToggle('fast');
    return false;
});
```

My click function is this link:

```
<a href="#" id="more">More about us</a>
```

How do I get that 'More about us' text to change to read 'Less about us' when the `#extra` div is visible? When the same link is clicked to hide the div, I'd like the text of the link to change back to read 'More about us'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just toggle the text ?

```
$('#more').click(function() {
    $('#extra').slideToggle('fast');
    $('#more').text(function(_,txt) {
        var ret='';

        if ( txt == 'More about us' ) {
           ret = 'Less about us';
           $(this).css('background','url(link/to/image1.png)');
        }else{
           ret = 'More about us';
           $(this).css('background','url(link/to/image2.png)');
        }
        return ret;
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Use this code :

```
$('#more').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).text('less about us');
    if($('#extra').is(':visible')){
          jQuery(this).text('Less about us');
    }else{
          jQuery(this).text('More about us');
    }
    $('#extra').slideToggle('fast');
    return false;
});
```

Here is the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/AAFaY/

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$('#more').click(function() {
    var more = $(this);
    $('#extra').slideToggle('fast', function(){
        more.html(s.text() == 'More about us' ? 'Less about us' : 'More about us');
    });
    return false;
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HFcvH/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for this Dinesh's solution is probably most eficient end elegant
in jQuery, for hure

```js
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('#more').click(function() {
        var s = $(this);
            $('#extra').slideToggle('fast', function() {
                s.html(s.text() == 'More..' ? 'Less..' : 'More..');
            });
            return false;
    });
});
```

```css
#wrapp {
  height: 38vh;
  width: 40vw;
  margin: 50px 50px;
  left: 10%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
}
#wrapp #more {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: yellow;
}  
#extra {
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1.2vh auto;
}
#extra p {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  padding-top: 3.6vh;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: bold;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"> 
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapp">
            <header>
                <h1>Heading...</h1>
            </header>        
           
            <a href="#" id="more">Less..</a>                
            <div id="extra"><p>Whatewer...</p></div>      
            
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('#more').click(function() {
        var s = $(this);
            $('#extra').slideToggle('fast', function() {
                s.html(s.text() == 'More..' ? 'Less..' : 'More..');
            });
            return false;
    });
});
```

```css
#wrapp {
  height: 38vh;
  width: 40vw;
  margin: 50px 50px;
  left: 10%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
}
#wrapp #more {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: yellow;
}  
#extra {
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1.2vh auto;
}
#extra p {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  padding-top: 3.6vh;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: bold;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"> 
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapp">
            <header>
                <h1>Heading...</h1>
            </header>        
           
            <a href="#" id="more">Less..</a>                
            <div id="extra"><p>Whatewer...</p></div>      
            
        </div>
    </body>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('#more').click(function() {
        var s = $(this);
            $('#extra').slideToggle('fast', function() {
                s.html(s.text() == 'More..' ? 'Less..' : 'More..');
            });
            return false;
    });
});
```

```css
#wrapp {
  height: 38vh;
  width: 40vw;
  margin: 50px 50px;
  left: 10%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
}
#wrapp #more {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: yellow;
}  
#extra {
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1.2vh auto;
}
#extra p {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  padding-top: 3.6vh;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: bold;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"> 
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapp">
            <header>
                <h1>Heading...</h1>
            </header>        
           
            <a href="#" id="more">Less..</a>                
            <div id="extra"><p>Whatewer...</p></div>      
            
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would actually suggest using jquery to only toggle the class name and have css toggle the text as such:

```js
$('.btn').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.btn::before{
  content:"Show";
}

.btn.active::before{
  content:"Hide";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class='btn'></a>
```