# Toggle a background images position

Tags: jquery, css, image, toggle, slidetoggle

I have the below code that show/hides a div whilst changing the text depending on whether the div is displayed or not:

```
$('#more').click(function() {
    $('#extra').slideToggle('fast');
    $('#more').text(function(_,txt) {
        return txt == 'More about us' ? 'Less about us' : 'More about us';
    });
    return false;
});
```

On the `#more` link I have an arrow pointing down (for the 'More about us' text, when the div is hidden) but I'd like to change this arrow to point up when the div is visible and the text reads 'Less about us'. How can I edit the above code to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722229/toggle-text-when-link-is-clicked/17722260#comment25831483_17722260

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#more').click(function() {
    $('#extra').slideToggle('fast');
    $('#more').text(function(_,txt) {
        var ret='';

        if ( txt == 'More about us' ) {
           ret = 'Less about us';
           $(this).css('background','url(link/to/image1.png)');
        }else{
           ret = 'More about us';
           $(this).css('background','url(link/to/image2.png)');
        }
        return ret;
    });
    return false;
});
```

Courtesy

[Toggle text when link is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722229/toggle-text-when-link-is-clicked/17722260#comment25831483_17722260)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create two css classes, and then just set the correct class:

```
$('#more').removeClass("arrowdown");
$('#more').addClass("arrowup");
```

And vice versa , depending on the text you just set.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using some code that was updated on a previous question:

```
$('#more').click(function() {
    $('#extra').slideToggle('fast');
    $('#more').text(function(_,txt) {
        var ret='';

        if ( txt == 'More about us' ) {
           ret = 'Less about us';
           $(this).css('background','url(link/to/image1.png)');
        }else{
           ret = 'More about us';
           $(this).css('background','url(link/to/image2.png)');
        }
        return ret;
    });
    return false;
});
```